# White box while going back from UIViewController to tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I realised that I have a white box next to my view controller when going back to the tableViewController. I checked my code if I have any frames or subviews or something like that.

Here's a gif that shows my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P69wk.gif

And here's the content of my MasterViewController.h and .m (which is the tableview)

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface XMMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "XMMasterViewController.h"
#import "XMDetailViewController.h"
#import "XMEditViewController.h"


@interface XMMasterViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) XMDetailViewController *detailViewController;
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)dataChangedFromICloud:(NSNotification*)note;
@end

@implementation XMMasterViewController


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (XMDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataChangedFromICloud:) name:@"databaseChanged" object:nil];
    });
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue: NSLocalizedString(@"name", nil) forKey:@"title"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"creationDate"];
    [newManagedObject setValue: nil forKey:@"text"];
    [newManagedObject setValue: NSLocalizedString(@"place", nil) forKey:@"location"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addSegue" sender:newManagedObject];

}

#pragma mark - Table View
/*- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Noch zu erledigen",@"Erledigt",nil];

    return array.count;
}*/


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
        self.detailViewController.selectionView.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addSegue"]) {
        XMEditViewController *editVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        editVC.detailItem = sender;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Todo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"done == %@", @(NO)];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"done" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}





- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test";
    NSDate *date = [object valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSDate *time = [object valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSDateFormatter *timeformat = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [timeformat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"display",nil), [format stringFromDate:date], [timeformat stringFromDate:time]];
}

#pragma mark - iCloud refresh

- (void)dataChangedFromICloud:(NSNotification*)note
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *error = nil;

        if(self.fetchedResultsController) {
            if([self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error! %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }

    });
}



@end
```

And here are the .h and .m files of the DetailViewController (the one, that gives me the white space when going back)

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XMDetailViewController : UIViewController {
//    IBOutlet UISwitch *switchButton;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *todoTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *selectionView;
- (IBAction)todoDoneTouched:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)shareTouched:(id)sender;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "XMDetailViewController.h"
#import "XMEditViewController.h"
#import "XMInfoViewController.h"

#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface XMDetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation XMDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.titleLabel.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"title"];
        self.todoTextView.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"text"];
        self.locationLabel.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"location"];

        NSDate *date = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [format setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
        NSDate *time = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
        NSDateFormatter *timeformat = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [timeformat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"display",nil), [format stringFromDate:date], [timeformat stringFromDate:time]];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   // switchButton.on = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"done"] boolValue];


}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)todoDoneTouched:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.detailItem setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"done"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.detailItem managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error = nil;


    if(![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"error1",nil), error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.selectionView.hidden = NO;
    }


    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTodo" message:NSLocalizedString(@"done2",nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"done1",nil));


}
/*-(IBAction)theSwitch {
    if (switchButton.on) {
        [self.detailItem setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"done"];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.detailItem managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error = nil;

        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"error1",nil), error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTodo" message:NSLocalizedString(@"done2",nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"done1",nil));

    } else {
        [self.detailItem setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"done"];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.detailItem managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error = nil;

        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"error1",nil), error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
*/


- (IBAction)shareTouched:(id)sender {
    NSString *titleString = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSDate *date = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSDate *time = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSDateFormatter *timeformat = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [timeformat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSString *initialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"post",nil), titleString, [format stringFromDate:date], [timeformat stringFromDate:time]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s.xnmn.de/mytodo"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon76x76@2x"];

    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:initialString, image, url, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editSegue"]){
        XMEditViewController *editVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        editVC.detailItem = self.detailItem;
    }
}



- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master",nil);
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}
@end
```

Maybe someone already had this issue or is aware of this and knows how to resolve this.

Comment: By "white box", you meant the tableview is empty when you goes back? How about show us some codes on your project? If possible, please update the project to GitHub and link here.

Comment: @Ricky theres pretty obviously a box that appears and covers the cell. The cell is already populated.

Comment: @Ricky I added the relevant code to the question.

Comment: @MiloGosnell yep, but I don't know from where it is, because in the iPad Version of the app it isn't there.